# How to display Excel Spreadsheet in Unity?

Tags: pdf

I need to display Excel Spreadsheet inside of Unity with edit and read feature. This is a PDF file image but Excel file displays like this:

[image: ]]

Comment: why do not use libreoffice?, you can use it --headless manner and further convert like `soffice --headless --convert-to jpg file.xlsx  file.jpg
`

Comment: Are you asking how to install Microsoft Excel in Ubuntu?